# R stacked barplot

Tags: r, plot, statistics

I have the following dataframe:

```
Var1    Var2
FALSE   FALSE
FALSE   TRUE
TRUE    FALSE
FALSE   TRUE
FALSE   FALSE
```

Question 1: When we look at just 1 column, how can i generate a simple stacked bar-plot (all falses on top of trues)?

Question 2: How can i put these two (stacked) bar-plots next to each other in one plot?

I need these plots as part of an assignment and i am not allowed to use external libraries (such as ggplot)

thank you

Comment: I'm not going to do your homework for you, but you should start by reading the help page found by typing `?barplot`.  Also look at the examples found there.

Comment: already did quite a bit of research but the "beside = FALSE" argument doesn't seem to work, it just puts 2 bars next to eachother ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The questions has already been answered but I will provide mine anyway since I already did the work. :)

```
    df<-data.frame(Var1=c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE), 
                   Var2=c(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE))
    barplot(t(rbind(Var1=table(df$Var1), var2=table(df$Var2))))
```

[image: Logical count]

Answer (score 3):

Your data:

```
dat<-read.table(text="Var1    Var2
FALSE   FALSE
FALSE   TRUE
TRUE    FALSE
FALSE   TRUE
FALSE   FALSE", header = TRUE)
```

It works with

```
barplot(rbind(colSums(dat), colSums(!dat)))
```

[image]

Comment: im very happy with your fast answer, but how would i implement this in a data frame that has more columns then the ones is want to plot (you use a table, how should i make a table out of a data-frame)?

Comment: @Michael (1) This approach does not depend on the number of columns. (2) I do not use a table but a data frame (actually the function `read.table` returns a data frame).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, thanks to Dr. Mike's answer i can also implement it (was quite simple but i'm new to R)